# CSS border only showing on one of the posts I'm getting from database

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, jsp

[image]By post I mean, a set of markup having title, its content and an accordion containing comments. I'm using JSP on server side and MySQL on database side. My code structure for JSP is as follows:

```
   <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
    <h1 style="color: crimson;">All Posts</h1>
    <br/>

    <section class = "post">
    <%
      try{
        con = JdbcUtil.getCon();
        start = JdbcUtil.getStart();
        String sql = "select * from post_master order by post_date desc";
        start = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        ResultSet rs = start.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next())
        {
           postid = rs.getInt("postid");
           title = rs.getString("post_heading");
           content = rs.getString("post_content");
           content = content.replaceAll("\n","<br />");
           title = title.replaceAll("\n","<br />");
           date = rs.getTimestamp("post_date");
           int regidpost = rs.getInt("regid");
           Object o5 = s.load(Register.class, new Integer(regidpost));
           Register regpost = (Register)o5;
           String post_usertype = regpost.getUsertype();

            String post_clgid = "";
            if(post_usertype.equals("Student"))
            {
              post_clgid = StudentJdbc.getClgid(regidpost);
            }
           //add later subname feature for tags
      %>
      <article class="title"><h3><%=title%></h3></article>
      <%
        if(post_usertype.equals("Student"))
        { 
      %>
      <span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>  <%=date%> by <a href="ViewStudent.jsp?regid=<%=regidpost%>&clgid=<%=post_clgid%>" ><%=regpost.getName()%></a>
      <%
        }
        else
        {
      %>
          <span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>  <%=date%> by <a href="ViewOea.jsp?regid=<%=regidpost%>" ><%=regpost.getName()%></a>
      <%
        }
      %>    
      <hr/>
      <article class = "content">
        <%=content%>
      </article>
      <br>
      <div class = "panel-group" id = "accordion">
        <div class = "panel panel-default">
          <div class = "panel-heading">
            <h4 class = "panel-title">
              <a href = "#<%=postid%>" class = "accordion-toggle" data-toggle = "collapse" data-parent = "#accordion"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></span> Comments&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="badge"><%= MiscJdbc.countComments(postid) %></span> </a>
            </h4>
          </div>
        <div id = "<%=postid%>" class = "panel-collapse collapse">
          <div class = "panel-body">

            <article class="comment">
              <a class="comment-img" href="#non">
                <img src="<%=reg.getPic()%>" alt="" width="50" height="50">
              </a>
              <div class="comment-body">
                <div class="text">

                <!---------------COMMENT FORM---------------------------->  
                  <form action="addComment?postid=<%=postid%>" method="POST">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <textarea id="inputComment" rows="9" cols="150" wrap = "hard" name ="comment" placeholder="Post Content" class="form-control" autofocus></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <input type="submit" class=" btn btn-primary">
                    </div>
                  </form>

                </div>
              </div>
            </article>
      <%
         // Object o3 = s.load(PostComment.class, new Integer(postid));
        //PostComment commentobj = (PostComment)o3;
          try{
            Connection con2 = JdbcUtil.getCon();
            PreparedStatement start2 = JdbcUtil.getStart();
            String sql2 = "select * from post_comment where postid = ?";
            start2 = con2.prepareStatement(sql2);
            start2.setInt(1, postid);
            ResultSet rs2 = start2.executeQuery();
            while(rs2.next())
            {
              comment = rs2.getString("comment_content");
              comment = comment.replaceAll("\n", "<br />");
              cmntdate = rs2.getTimestamp("comment_date");
              out.println("comment");  
              int regid2 = rs2.getInt("regid");

              Object o4 = s.load(Register.class, new Integer(regid2));
              Register regcmnt = (Register)o4;
              int cmnt_regid = regcmnt.getRegid();
              String cmnt_clgid = "";
              String cmnt_usertype = regcmnt.getUsertype();
              if(cmnt_usertype.equals("Student"))
              {
                cmnt_clgid = StudentJdbc.getClgid(cmnt_regid);

              }
      %>
              <article class="comment">
                <a class="comment-img" href="#non">
                  <img src="<%=regcmnt.getPic()%>" alt="" width="50" height="50">
                </a>
                <div class="comment-body">
                  <div class="text">
                    <%=comment%>
                    <!--Comment here is displayed.-->
                  </div>
      <%
                  if(cmnt_usertype.equals("Student"))
                  {
      %>              
                    <p class="attribution">By <a href="ViewStudent.jsp?regid=<%=cmnt_regid%>&clgid=<%=cmnt_clgid%>"> <%=regcmnt.getName()%></a> at <%=cmntdate%></p>
      <%
                  }
                  else{
      %>   
                    <p class="attribution">By <a href="ViewOea.jsp?regid=<%=cmnt_regid%>"> <%=regcmnt.getName()%></a> at <%=cmntdate%></p>
      <%
                }
      %>            
                </div>

              </article> 

      <%
            }
            start2.close();
            rs2.close();
            con2.close();
          }catch(SQLException ex)
          {
            out.println(ex);
          }
      %>        


          </div> <!--panel-body closes-->
        </div> <!--resume-ac closes-->
      </div> <!--panel panel-default closes-->
    </div> <!--accordion closes-->
    </section>
   <hr>   
      <%
        }
        rs.close();
        start.close();
        con.close();
      }catch(SQLException ex){
        out.println(ex);
      }

    %>


  </div>
```

All the posts and comments are coming here in the form of JSP scriptlets using ResultSet. 
The CSS is relatively simple:

```
.post{
  border-style: groove;
  border-color: #795548;
  padding: 10px;
}

.title h3
{
  color: #cca01e;
}
```

But the border is coming around only first post and not around others. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Questions seeking help ("**why isn't, or how to make, this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a _specific problem or error and the **shortest code necessary**_ to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I want border around all the posts, as stated in the question

Comment: Read all the comment, not only to the first comma.

Comment: Do you have a publicly accessible link?  Or do you have an example of the HTML markup produced when there are multiple posts?  As it is, it is nearly impossible to help.

Comment: @conman124 A _public link_ is as as bad as no code in the question.

Comment: I have included a snapshot now of the problem. Sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: Image is good, still, please read my comment fully so you understand what it takes to post a proper question, which this still is not

Comment: there is extra </article> closing tag and extra </div> as well. fix your HTML

Comment: Added the complete code

Comment: @LGSon Is it alright now?

Comment: Please, simply read my first comment carefully and follow those instructions

Comment: @LGSon my guess is that the problem is some sort of malformed HTML, so a public link would help.  I do agree that if the OP had taken the time to find the shortest code necessary, they probably would have solved the problem themselves or at least made it easier for anyone else to spot it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what the issue is, I was not able to reproduce it with the original code you provided (before you added all the JSP stuff)

Two minor things, there duplicate closing tags (as pointed out in the comments) and you have not indicated if they are the culprit or not.  I commented them out in the code below.

See if this your desired output.  Otherwise, you will need to clarify a bit more what it is that you want (the desired output)

Hope this helps

```css
.post {
  border-style: groove;
  border-color: #795548;
  padding: 10px;
}

.title h3 {
  color: #cca01e;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
  <h1 style="color: #664EB0FF;">All Posts</h1>
  <br>
  <section class="post">
    <article class="title">
      <h3>Section 1</h3>
    </article>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span> May 22, 2017 by Sahil Dhawan
    <hr>
    <article class="content">
      Main content
    </article>

    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a href="#comments-acc" class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></span> Comments&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="badge">Comments Count</span> </a>
          </h4>
        </div>
        <!-- panel heading -->
        <!-- comments-acc -->
        <div id="comments-acc" class="panel-collapse collapse">

          <!-- panel-body -->
          <div class="panel-body">

            <article class="comment">
              <a class="comment-img" href="#non">
                <img src="#">
              </a>
              <div class="comment-body">
                <div class="text">
                  <p>Hello, this is an example comment</p>
                </div>
                <p class="attribution">by <a href="#non">Joe Bloggs</a> at 14:23pm, 4th Dec 2010</p>
              </div>
            </article>

            <!-- this is extra 
            </article>  
            -->

          </div>
          <!--panel-body closes-->
        </div>
        <!--resume-ac closes-->
      </div>
      <!--panel panel-default closes-->
    </div>
    <!--accordion closes-->
  </section>


  <!-- ANOTHER SECTION -->
  <section class="post">
    <article class="title">
      <h3>Section 2</h3>
    </article>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span> May 22, 2017 by Sahil Dhawan
    <hr>
    <article class="content">
      Main content
    </article>
  </section>

  <!-- ANOTHER SECTION -->
  <section class="post">
    <article class="title">
      <h3>Section 3</h3>
    </article>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span> May 22, 2017 by Sahil Dhawan
    <hr>
    <article class="content">
      Main content
    </article>
  </section>



</div>

<!-- this is extra 
</div>
-->
```